# How to apply UI virtualization to ScrollViewer in WinRT

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

Is it possible to apply UI virtualization to ScrollViewer in WinRT. In my application I am creating a line chart with the help of Polyline(Polyline embedded inside a scrollviewver). But in the current case, If it come more than 500 points. It blocks the UI during the time of interacting with the Map. So what I am trying to achieve is to apply kind of UI virtualization to scroll view. If anyone had any idea to solve this please help me.

Comment: You'd need to handle scrolling events, etc. There's not a simple solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I would handle a `Polyline` is I would break its data into sections, perhaps screen-wide ones (assuming horizontal-only scrolling), put a `Canvas` inside of the `ScrollViewer`, make the size (`Width`) of the `Canvas` the total size of the chart and put a few (say 5) `Polyline` controls in it and then on the `ViewChanged` event update the `Polyline` controls' `Canvas.Left` and `Points` properties to correspond to the area around the current view port of the `ScrollViewer`. That should give you smooth scrolling. Just don't add/remove or update the controls on each `ViewChanged` and only update `Canvas.Left` and `Points` when you need to - that is when you don't have a `Polyline` ready to display next to the current view port.